# Selecting the average of all values returned by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I find the average from this query using SQL:

```
SELECT  count(col1) as count FROM table1 GROUP BY col1 HAVING count > 1
```

I'm trying to find the average number of rows per `col1`

So far I managed to find the total amount of rows per `col1`, now I just need the avg

Comment: [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html#function_avg) ??

Comment: 'average number of rows per col1' - what does this mean? Do you mean the average of the values in col1? If so then replace count(col1) with AVG(col1)

Comment: Do you mean `avg(col1)`?  If not, can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

```
select avg( c ) 
from ( SELECT  count(col1) as c FROM table1 GROUP BY col1 HAVING count > 1 )
```

Comment: Notice that Randy did not use "count" as a column alias because it is a key word in sql.  +1

Answer (score 0):

For table you need alias and change `count` to `count(*)`.

Query:

```
SELECT avg(t1.c) AS avgcol1
FROM
  (SELECT count(col1) AS c
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t1
```